# Storage::disk Page not found --Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I am triying to upload a document with the Storage disk method. I can upload him in this the /storage/app/public .But now I want to allow the user to dowload into his computer. So that is my App Url in the .env

```
APP_URL=http://backend-debug.localhost
```

In the filesystems.php I create a new link "import"

```
'import' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage/app/public',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

finally I return him with

```
$response['url'] = Storage::disk('import')->url('export-error/'.$filename);
    Log::info('url = '.$response['url'] );
    return $response;
```

The log gives this information.

> url = http://backend-debug.localhost/storage/app/public/export-error/error_file.csv

I am using Laravel 5.6 
I can't dowload my Document into my pc 
Any idea ? 
Thank you

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Replace `env(APP_URL)` with `public_path()`

Comment: Does it give 404 error?

Comment: I should be able to download to my computer but I just have a redirect on a blank page.

Comment: Does that file exists on `storage/app/public/export-error/error_file.csv`?

Comment: He gives me http://localhost:4200/mnt/data/backend/public/storage/app/public/export-error/error_file.csv. I use angular.

Comment: Yes 
user@dev:/mnt/data/coty/ezygtn/backend/storage/app/public/export-error$ ls
error_file.csv

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#file-downloads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking to `http://localhost:4200/mnt/data/backend/public/storage/app/public/export-error/error_file.csv` URL it seems that your `import` filesystem connection is correct.

Here, Laravel tries to find the **storage** directory inside the **public** directory which is correct. To ensure this, you need to **symlink** the storage directory inside a **public** directory. Laravel provides a command to create one if not exist.

To create symlink, run following command.

`php artisan storage:link`

This command will create a symlink of storage directory in public directory. If you are using windows then simply create a shortcut of storage directory inside public directory.

For more information visit, https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#the-public-disk

Thanks.

Comment: I already do that but I forgot to change Storage::disk('import') to Storage::disk('public ') ... Thank you so much :) In fact I need to add a folder into public and not storage too